# Definite Integral Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, math, linear-algebra, symbolic-integration

I'm working on a project in `Matlab` and need to find the area between two lines (intersecting in a point `(xIntersection,yIntersection)` in the interval [-1,+1].  So the idea is to subtract the two lines and integrate between [-1, xIntersection] and [xIntersection, +1], sum the results and if it's negative, change its sign.

For details on how I find the intersection of the two lines check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection).

I'm using `Matlab's` function [`int()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html), here a snippet of my code:

```
xIntersection = ((x_1 * y_2 - y_1 * x_2) * (x_3 - x_4) - (x_1 - x_2) * (x_3 * y_4 - y_3 * x_4) ) / ((x_1 - x_2) * (y_3 - y_4) - (y_1 - y_2) * (x_3 - x_4));

syms x;
integral = int( line 1 - line 2 expression containing x, x, -1, xIntersection) + int( line 1 - line 2 expression containing x, x, xIntersection, 1)
if(integral < 0),
    integral = integral * -1;
end
```

The problem is that `Matlab` doesn't return a real value for the integral but instead an expression containing a division, i.e. :

> 107813370750829368626584124420059/162259276829213363391578010288128

This prevents me from been able to do further operations with the result of integration.

1. Any idea of why this is the returned value?
2. Any idea of a possible loophole?

Comment: I don't have the symbolic math toolbox, but couldn't you transform your result by `double(x)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area between two curves is equal to the integral of the difference between the "upper curve" and the "lower curve", so you have an incorrect sign in the second integrand.

The main problem is however that you are using *symbolic* expressions. That means MATLAB will try its very best to give you an *exact* answer, rather than an approximate one (numerical).

If you want numeric outcomes, use numeric methods:

```
result = ...
    quadgk( @(x) line1(x) - line2(x), -1, xIntersection) + ...
    quadgk( @(x) line2(x) - line1(x), xIntersection, 1 );
```

or

```
result = ...
    quadgk(@(x) abs(line1(x) - line2(x)), -1, +1);
```

for short :)

I believe `integral` is the function of choice in newer versions of MATLAB ( > R2010a), but I can't test this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't neccesarily agree with @Rody on this. In general: if you have the chance, why not get the exact result. 
If it can be solved, at least you don't need to worry about numerical problems too much.

Simply [wrap the result with `double`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/conversion.html) as suggested by @thewaywewalk.

Comment: I guess I'll try both and check what are the differences. thks for your advice

Comment: prediction: the outcomes will differ no more than 1e-14. The speed of the symbolic one will be 10x slower than the numeric one.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - that is correct, and that is why I accepted your answer! ;D