# Area between two lines inside the square [-1,+1] x [-1,+1]

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, numerical-integration, algebra

I'm working on a project in `Matlab` and need to find the area between two lines inside of the square `[-1,+1]x[-1,+1]` intersecting in a point `(xIntersection,yIntersection)`.  So the idea is to subtract the two lines and integrate between [-1, xIntersection] and [xIntersection, +1], sum the results and if it's negative, change its sign.

For details on how I find the intersection of the two lines check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection).

I'm using `Matlab's` function [`integral()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), here a snippet of my code:

```
xIntersection = ((x_1 * y_2 - y_1 * x_2) * (x_3 - x_4) - (x_1 - x_2) * (x_3 * y_4 - y_3 * x_4) ) / ((x_1 - x_2) * (y_3 - y_4) - (y_1 - y_2) * (x_3 - x_4));

d = @(x) g(x) - f(x);
result = integral(d, -1, xIntersection) - int( d, xIntersection, 1)
if(result < 0),
    result = result * -1;
end
```

Note that I defined previously in the code `g(x)` and `f(x)` but haven't reported it in the snippet.

The problem is that I soon realized that the lines could intersect either inside or outside of the square, furthermore they could intersect the square on any of its sides and the number of possible combinations grows up very quickly.

I.e.:

[image][image][image][image]

These are just 4 cases, but considering that f(+1), f(-1), g(+1), g(-1) could be inside the interval [-1,+1], above it or under it and that the intersection could be inside or outside of the square the total number is 3*3*3*3*2 = 162.

Obviously in each case the explicit function to integrate in order to get the area between the two lines is different, but I can't possibly think of writing a switch case for each one.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you define “between the lines”? What is supposed to happen if the lines are at 90°?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734671/definite-integral-matlab/18734972#18734972) still applies, for the most part.

If you want to compute the area of the region bounded by the smaller angle of the two lines and the boundaries of the square, then you can forget about the intersection, and forget about all the different cases.

You can just use the fact that

- the area of the square S is equal to 4
- the value of this integral

  ```
  A = quadgk(@(x) ...
      abs( max(min(line1(x),+1),-1) - max(min(line2(x),+1),-1) ), -1, +1);
  ```

  gives you the area between the lines (sometimes the large angle, sometimes the small angle)
- the value of  of `min(A, S-A)` is the correct answer (always the small angle).

Comment: +1 for the answer, and if I could another +1 for finding this new question ;D

Comment: Let me know what you think of my answer, although I believe your's is better cause less time consuming and it's not an empirical approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming “between the lines” means “inside the smaller angle formed by the lines”:

With the lines `l` and `h`,  `S := [-1,+1]x[-1,+1]` and `B` as the border of `S`.

Transform `l` to the form `l_1 + t*l_2` with `l_1` and `l_2` beeing vectors. Do the same for h.

- If the intersection is not inside `S`, find the 4 intersections of `l` and `h` with `B`. Sort them so you get a convex quadrilateral. [Calculate its area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Area_of_a_convex_quadrilateral).
- Else:

  - Find the intersection point `p` and [find the intersection angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) `α` between `l_2` and `h_2`. and then check:

    - If `α` in `[90°,180°]` or `α` in `[270°,360°]`, swap `l` and `h`.
    - If `α > 180°`, set `l_2 = −l_2`
  - Set `l_1 := h_1 := p`. Do once for positive `t` and negative `t`
    (forwards and backwards along `l_2` and `h_2` from `p`):

    - Find intersections `s_l` and `s_h` of `l` and `h` with `B`.
    - If on same border of `B`: compute [area of triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle) `s_l`, `s_h`, `p`
    - If on adjacent borders of `B`: find the corner `c` of `B` in between the hit borders and once again sort the four points `s_l`, `s_h`, `p` and `c` so you get an convex quadrilateral and calculate it’s area.
    - If on opposite borders, find the matching side of `B` (you can do this by looking at the direction of `s_l-p`). Using its two corner points `c_1` and `c_2`, you now have 5 points that form a polygon. Sort them so the polygon is convex and [calculate its area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid).

This is still quite a few cases, but I don’t think there’s a way around that. You can simplify this somewhat by also using the polygon formula for the triangle and the quadrilateral.

How to sort the points so you get a convex polygon/quadrilateral: select any one of them as `p_1` and then sort the rest of the points according to angle to `p_1`.

If you define an `intersection` function and a `polygon_area` that takes a list of points, sorts them and returns the area, this algorithm should be rather simple to implement.

**edit:** Image to help explain the comment:
[image]

Comment: thanks for posting, still trying to understand your answer! ;D thks for pointing out that between means indeed inside the smaller angle. I have a couple thing to ask if you can help me: I think l_1 is a scalar and not a vector, correct? And what do you mean by swap l and h? And finally what do you mean by Set l_1 := h_1 := p. Do once for positive t and negative t (forwards and backwards along l_2 and h_2 from p):?

Comment: no, `l_1` is a vector – it’s the “starting point” of the line (=any point on the line). Which is why we can set both `l_1` and `h_1` to `p` later on, as we know that `p` is on both `l` and `h`. “Swap `l` and `h`” means “set l_1=h_1 and l_2=h_2  and set `h_1` and `h_2` to what `l_1` and `l_2` where before.

Comment: For the “positive t”: say `l` intersects `B` in `s_1` and `s_2`. Now there is a (scalar) `t_1`, so that `p + t_1•l_2 = s_1` and a (scalar) `t_2` so that `p + t_2•l_2 = s_2`. Now one of those `t` is going to be positive and one of them is going to be negative. We know this, because `p` is between `s_1` and `s_2`. Did that help?

Comment: Added an image to maybe clear up the situation. The whole point of the swapping, reversing and positive/negative direction is to make sure that you indeed look at the smaller angle, not the wider. But I think the swapping might actually not be required.

Comment: I posted an answer and would like to hear your comments on it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys thanks for your answers, I also thought of an empirical method to find the area between the lines and wanted to share it for the sake of discussion and completeness.

If you take a large number of random points within the square `[-1,+1]x[-1,+1]` you can measure the area as the fraction of the points which fall in the area between the two lines.

Here's a little snippet and two images to show the different accuracy of empirical result obtained with different number of points.

```
minX = -1;
maxX = +1;

errors = 0;
size = 10000;

for j=1:size,

    %random point in [-1,+1]
    T(j,:) = minX + (maxX - minX).*rand(2,1); 

    %equation of the two lines is used to compute the y-value
    y1 = ( ( B(2) - A(2) ) / ( B(1) - A(1) ) ) * (T(j,1) - A(1)) + A(2);
    y2 = (- W(1) / W(2)) * T(j,1) -tresh / W(2);

    if(T(j,2) < y1),
        %point is under line one
        Y1 = -1;
    else
        %point is above line one
        Y1 = +1;
    end

    if(T(j,2) < y2),
        %point is under line two 
        Y2 = -1;
    else
        %point is above line two
        Y2 = +1;
    end

    if(Y1 * Y2 < 0),

        errors = errors + 1;
        scatter(T(j,1),T(j,2),'fill','r')
    else
        scatter(T(j,1),T(j,2),'fill','g')
    end

end

area = (errors / size) / 4;
```

And here are two images, it sure takes longer than the solution posted by @Rody but as you can see you can make it accurate.

- Number of points = 2000

[image: Number of points = 2000]

Number of points = 10000

[image: Number of points = 10000]

Comment: While an interesting idea, this method is very inaccurate/slow. I would recommend using a grid instead of random points – that way you get a more predictable result and then it also becomes clear how many points you need to get an accurate result if the angle is small. Maybe more precise: The absolute error is controllable, but the relative error will get very big for small angles. And if you take a lot of points, this method gets incredibly slow for an actually rather simple calculation.

Comment: Did you ever hear of [Monte Carlo Integration] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)? :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile, but you get the idea :)

Comment: @Chronial and Rody - thks for feedback guys, you helped me a lot on this.  I'll stick with Rody's answer cause it was the fastest, accurate and elegant one!